# Entity Framework Core saves old data when creating brand new migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Entity Framework Core with ASP.NET Core MVC to set up connection between my site and a database, using a code-first approach. For the most part it works alright.

But I've now come to struggle with a problem where it seems like old data is somewhere cached and used for new migrations. Even when I delete the whole migration folder and database. I've gotten different errors due to this, but one example is the following:

> The seed entity for entity type 'ResourceField' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'ResourceFieldDataLevel'

which is reasonable enough. My `ResourceField` seed does not contain a `ResourceFieldDataLevel`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ResourceField>().HasData(
                new ResourceField { ResourceFieldId = 1, Level = 1,
                VillageId = 1, TypeOfResource = ResourceFieldType.Clay },
```

But that's because the class `ResourceField` does not at all contain that value.

```
public class ResourceField
{
        public ResourceField()
        {
        }

        [Key]
        public int ResourceFieldId { get; set; }
        public ResourceFieldType TypeOfResource { get; set; }
        public int VillageId { get; set; }
        public virtual Village Village { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

Thing is, it did. I was testing different things, adding/removing stuff. So at one point, there was such a property. It seems like EF refuses to let go of old migrations. Thus keep using stuff that doesn't exist anymore.

I've deleted the whole migration folder and I've deleted the database, so it creates everything brand new.

I get the error after running:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

Similar problems have been solved by doing a batch-build clean. Did nothing for me.

How do I make Entity Framework Core forget about everything that has been, and just start fresh from what I have? I feel like that should be done when you remove migrations and the database.

Comment: What happens if you search the entire solution for ResourceFieldDataLevel?

Comment: Zero references

Comment: If you get an error about migration you can see that error when you try the build. ```rm -rf obj bin```after that ```dotnet build```, lets see whats the result. because you told when you were searching ```ResourceFieldDataLevel```there was no result.

Answer (score 1):

So what finally seemed to work was removing migration and database (yet again).
Then commenting away all parts of OnModelCreating containing seed data.

Deleted migrations and database yet again.

Uncommented and it works with exactly the same code.